# A fast way to compare interval

Tags: performance-tuning, list-manipulation, compile, intervals

I have a list of intervall.
Some of these intervals are disjoint, some are overlapped and some are included in others. To leave no ambiguity about my explanation, you can see the following examples:

{1, 2} and {3, 4} are disjointed.
{1, 3} and {2, 4} are overlaped.
{2,3} are included in {1,4}.

I would like to identify any intervals in a list that are completely included in others.
For example:

{2,3} are included in {1,4}
{2,4} are included in {1,4}
{1,3} are included in {1,4}
ect ..

**Objectives**

---

The goal is to get the list of positions of all intervals that are included in others in order to eliminate them. It's important to notice here that the list to study is always sorted.

Example of list :

```
ListT = {{1, 8}, {2, 8}, {3, 8}, {4, 8}, {5, 10}, {6, 10}, {7, 11}, {8, 14}};
```

I already write an algorithm that I find too slow. It is unnecessary to expose here.
So I write the followings algorithm :

```
Supone[x_] := If[x > 1, True, False];

Tentative1[ListT] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T1, Step3T1, Step4T1, Step5T1, Step6T1,Res},

         Step2T1 = Map[Interval[#] &, ListT];

         Step3T1 = Table[
                         IntervalMemberQ[Step2T1[[i]], Step2T1[[j]]],
                         {i, 1, Length@Step2T1, 1},
                         {j, 1, Length@Step2T1, 1}
                        ];

         Step4T1 = DeleteCases[Step3T1, False, Infinity];

         Step5T1 = Map[Count[#, True] &, Step4T1];

         Step6T1 = Position[Step5T1, _?Supone];

         Res = (Flatten@Step6T1) + 1

       ];
```

---

```
Tentative2[ListT_] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T2, Step3T2, Step4T2, Step5T2, Step6T2, Res},

         Step2T2 = Map[Interval[#] &, ListT];

         Step3T2 = Outer[IntervalMemberQ, Step2T2, Step2T2];

         Step4T2 = DeleteCases[Step3T2, False, Infinity];

         Step5T2 = Map[Count[#, True] &, Step4T2];

         Step6T2 = Position[Step5T2, _?Supone];

         Res = (Flatten@Step6T2) + 1;

       ];
```

---

```
Tentative3[ListT_] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T3, Step3T3, Step4T3, Step5T3, Step6T3,Res},

        Step2T3 =  Map[Interval[#] &, ListT];

        Step3T3 = Intersection[Step2T3,IntervalIntersection @@@ Subsets[Step2T3, {2}]];

        Step4T3 = Map[Position[Step2T3, #] &, Step3T3];

        Res = Flatten@Step4T3

       ];
```

---

```
IMQ[x_, y_] :=
  Block[
        {Memo, Res}, 
        If[
           x[[1]] <= y[[1]],       
           If[x[[1]] <= y[[1]] && x[[2]] >= y[[2]], Memo = True, Memo = False];,
           Memo = False;
          ];
         Res = Memo
       ];

FBS =
  Compile[
          {{List, _Real, 2}, {Interv, _Real, 1}},
          Module[
                 {i, j, st, end, xmin, xmax, Restr, Testlog},
                 xmin = Interv[[1]];
                 xmax = Interv[[-1]];
                 st = List[[All, 1]];
                 end = List[[All, 2]];
                 i = 1; While[end[[i]] < xmax, i++];
                 j = 1; While[end[[-j]] > xmax, j++];
                 Restr = List[[i ;; -j]];
                 Testlog = Count[Map[IMQ[#, Interv] &, Restr], True];
                 If[Testlog > 1, 1, -1]
                ],
            Parallelization -> True,
            "RuntimeOptions" -> "Speed"
          ];

Tentative4[ListT_] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T4, Step3T4, Step4T4, Step5T4, Step6T4, Res},

         Step2T4 = ListT;

         Step3T4 = Position[Map[FBS[Step2T4, #] &, Step2T4], 1];

         Res = Flatten@Step3T4
       ];
```

---

```
Tentative5[ListT_] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T5, Step3T5, Step4T5, Step5T5, Step6T5, Res},

         Step2T5 = ListT;
         Step3T5 =
              Module[
                     {a, b},
                     {a, b} =Transpose[Outer[Plus, -Step2T5, Step2T5, 1], {2,3,1}];
                     SparseArray[Total[UnitStep[a] UnitStep[-b]] -1]["AdjacencyLists"]
                    ]
              ];
```

---

```
Tentative6[ListT_] :=
  Block[
         {Step2T6, Step3T6, Step4T6, Step5T6, Step6T6, Res},

         Step2T6 = ListT;
         Step3T6 = Pick[
                         Range@Length@Step2T6,
                         Map[MemberQ[Step2T6, {x_, y_} /; x <= #[[1]] && y >= #[[2]] && ! (x == #[[1]] && y == #[[2]])] &, Step2T6]
                       ]
            ];
```

---

```
GIMQ[x_, y_] :=
  Block[
        {Memo, Res},
              If[
                 x[[1]] <= y[[1]],

                 If[x[[1]] <= y[[1]] && x[[2]] >= y[[2]], Memo = True, Memo = False];,

                 If[y[[1]] <= x[[1]] && y[[2]] >=  x[[2]], Memo = True, Memo = False];
                ];
              Res = Memo
            ];

LIP[List_, i_] :=
  Module[
         {j, Res},
          j = i - 1;
          If[ 
             j!= 0,
             If[ GIMQ[List[[i]], List[[j]]] == True, Res = 1;, Res = -1;],
             Res = -1;
            ];
           Res
        ];  

Tentative7[ListT] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T7, Step3T7, Step4T7, Step5T7, Step6T7, Res},

         Step2T7 = ListT
         Step3T7 = Position[Map[LIP[Step2T7, #] &, Range[1, Length@Step2T7, 1]], 1];
         Res = Flatten@Step3T7

       ];
```

---

```
Tentative8[ListT] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T8, Step3T8, Step4T8, Step5T8, Step6T8, Res},

         Step2T8 = ListT
         Step3T8 = Pick[
                        Range[2,Length@Step2T8],
                        IntervalMemberQ@@@Partition[Interval/@Step28,2,1]
                       ]

       ];
```

**Timing**

---

With : `Length@List = 2000`

`Tentative1[List, Integer]` -> 10.15 seconds (Personal n°1)
`Tentative2[List, Integer]` -> 6.46 seconds (Rasher's n°1)
`Tentative3[List, Integer]` -> 3.34 seconds (Rasher's n°2)
`Tentative4[List, Integer]` -> 5.42 seconds (Personal n°2)
`Tentative5[List, Integer]` -> 7.72 seconds (Simon Woods n°1)
`Tentative6[List, Integer]` -> 6,48 seconds (Rasher's n°3)
`Tentative7[List, Integer]` -> 0.48 seconds (Personal n°3)
`Tentative7[List, Integer]` -> 0.45 seconds (Simon Woods n°2)

**Benchmark**

---

For `ListT = {{1, 8}, {2, 8}, {3, 8}, {4, 8}, {5, 10}, {6, 10}, {7, 11}, {8, 14}};`
The result is : `{2, 3, 4, 6}`
So we can read this as : {2, 8}, {3, 8}, {4, 8} and {6, 10} are included in other intervals. Which ? We don't care... The objective is to obtain theirs positions.

*The subject remains open. I'm interested in any solution that would be faster than the current one*.
*Additional questions*:
- *Is it possible to use Compile on LIP ? How ?*
- *What's the better ? use of Block or use of Module ?*

Comment: You question is quite unclear. What is it exactly you want? Is it something like given a list of intervals, return a list of those completely contained in some other interval in the list? If so, something like `Intersection[list, IntervalIntersection @@@ Subsets[list, {2}]]` might serve your needs. If you want a "True/False" table like your first example, something like `Outer[IntervalMemberQ, list, list]` should be quite quick.

Comment: @rasher. Informations added !

Comment: Still not clear to me. My best guess so far is that you want (1) to pick from your original list (call it $L1$) of interval all the intervals that are included in at lest one other interval in $L1$. Call the resulting (sub-)list $L2$.  Then test whether the union of all intervals in $L2$ is itself an interval. Is that it?

Comment: @A.G. I totally rewrite my post. Ask me if you have any other questions.

Comment: It is still not clear. Please could you include what the **result** should be for your example `ListT` and check that the posted code actually generates that result.

Comment: I add a benchmark part. Hope this will help you.

Comment: I'm still scratching my head as to what you want: you seem to show several differing outcomes (list pairs, truth table, positions). I don't want to have to decode code. Based on your last (position-based) update to OP, perhaps this does what you want: `Pick[Range@Length@list, 
 Map[MemberQ[
    list, {x_, y_} /; 
     x <= #[[1]] && y >= #[[2]] && ! (x == #[[1]] && y == #[[2]])] &, 
  list]]`

Comment: @rasher. You have fully understood what I want to do. Your method gives correct result but still a little slow. Anyway, I just found a very quick solution. I'll post soon.

Comment: I'm surprised you find Rasher's and my solutions so slow on a list of length 2000. For me they both take a fraction of a second. Perhaps your `ListT` is not a packed array. Try evaluating ``ListT = Developer`ToPackedArray[ListT];`` and run the benchmarks again.

Comment: Your comment has made ​​me aware of the existence of packed array. I inquired on it and it seems that it is widely used. At least I've learned something today. I am impatient to try this as soon as possible.

Answer (score 2):

Note that the following is the 1D analog of my [answer](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/a/154052/45431) to [How to remove those rectangle within another rectangle](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/151774/45431).

You say that you want the positions of included intervals so that you can eliminate them. In that case, you can just use the function `` Internal`ListMin `` to return a list with all of the subintervals eliminated. Basically, `` Internal`ListMin `` finds maximal elements based on the usual component-wise partial order. For example, if $(x_1, y_1)$ and $(x_2, y_2)$ are two elements, than you want to eliminate $(x_1, y_1)$ if both $x_1\ge x_2$ and $y_1 \le y_2$.  Alternatively, you want to eliminate $(x_1, y_1)$ if $x_2 \le x_1$ and $-y_2 \le -y_1$. This is just the usual component-wise order on $(x, -y)$. So, using `` Internal`ListMin `` gives:

```
ListT = {{1,8}, {2,8}, {3,8}, {4,8}, {5,10}, {6,10}, {7,11}, {8,14}};

Internal`ListMin[ListT . {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}] . {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}
```

> {{1, 8}, {8, 14}, {5, 10}, {7, 11}}

Rewriting as a function:

```
removeSubintervals[pairList_] := Internal`ListMin[pairList . {{0, 1}, {-1, 0}}] . {{0, -1}, {1, 0}}
```

And coming up with a bigger example:

```
pList = Table[RandomInteger[1000] {1, 1} + {0, RandomInteger[30]}, {10^5}];

removeSubintervals[pList]; // AbsoluteTiming
```

> {0.313088, Null}

Only .31 seconds for a pair list of length 10^5.

Answer (score 1):

**Update**

With the added information that it is sufficient to test each interval only against the preceding one, this will be fairly fast:

```
Pick[Range[2, Length@ListT], IntervalMemberQ @@@ Partition[Interval /@ ListT, 2, 1]]
```

**Original**

This version tests every interval against every other:

```
result = Module[{a, b},
    {a, b} = Transpose[Outer[Plus, -ListT, ListT, 1], {2, 3, 1}];
    SparseArray[Total[UnitStep[a] UnitStep[-b]] - 1]["AdjacencyLists"]];
```

Comment: Finally your solution is slightly faster than mine. I also tried to use ToPackedArray. I noticed no improvement in execution time. Code used :
`Needs [Developer ']`       

`NewListT = Developer'ToPackageArray [ListT]`

Answer (score 1):

Best known optimisation :

For a specific list :

```
Tentative8[ListT] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T8, Step3T8, Step4T8, Step5T8, Step6T8, Res},

         Step2T8 = ListT
         Step3T8 = Pick[
                        Range[2,Length@Step2T8],
                        IntervalMemberQ@@@Partition[Interval/@Step28,2,1]
                       ]

       ];
```

For a global list :

```
Tentative3[ListT_] :=
  Block[
        {Step2T3, Step3T3, Step4T3, Step5T3, Step6T3,Res},

        Step2T3 =  Map[Interval[#] &, ListT];

        Step3T3 = Intersection[Step2T3,IntervalIntersection @@@ Subsets[Step2T3, {2}]];

        Step4T3 = Map[Position[Step2T3, #] &, Step3T3];

        Res = Flatten@Step4T3

       ];
```

Comment: A couple of points - firstly please be aware that `List` is a **terrible** choice of variable name (as you used in `LIP`) because it is the symbol used by *Mathematica* as the head of lists. While it doesn't cause any problem here, it is generally good practice to avoid using built-in symbol names for your own variables.

Comment: Secondly, your `GIMQ` function may be more succinctly written as `GIMQ[{{a_, b_}, {c_, d_}}] := a <= c && b >= d`

Comment: Finally, I note that this solution relies on checking interval intersections only between adjacent list elements. So for example `Tentative7[{{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {6, 8}}]` returns `{2}` instead of `{2, 3}`. Is this the intended behaviour?

Comment: Firstly thank you for the 2 advices/improvements in your comments. Then according to your example, it is better for me that `Tentative7 [{{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {6, 8}}]` returns `{2,3}` instead of `{2}`. But in my case, it is impossible that the data I have to be treated have this configuration. In fact, I always have `{{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {3, 4}}` instead of `{{1, 10}, {2, 4}, {6, 8}}` for example. I did not realize this when I started looking for a solution.